# How do you make a div box fit all of it's contents, even if the content's height is larger than the viewport height?

Tags: html, css

I can't get the body, html, or the div to automatically change it's height to fit the text box.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="min-height: 100vh;overflow: auto;">
            <p style="position: absolute;height: 1500px;">Test</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Output:

Viewport height: 1091.430

Body and div height: 1075.430px

Text height:  1500px

Comment: Remove position absolute it's entirely unnecessary.

Comment: @Paulie_D Ok. I've done that. Is my question good now?

Comment: That should solve your problem

Comment: @Paulie_D That did indeed work, but I need my <p> to be absolute, as I want it to be on top of a image, on the actual webpage. I guess that would be a different question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `position: absolute;` fixes this issue.